# Is there any better/alternative way to pass variables to a page than this in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a really simple groupon like script for learning purposes now in holidays. What I posted below is the code that shows a deal and you have the option to buy it. When you click on buy, you are moved to checkout.php that displays also some info about the requested product.
**deal.php**

```
$dealid = (int)$_GET["id"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $dealid LIMIT 1";
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));

echo $row['name'];
echo '<br>';
echo '<a href="checkout.php?id='. $row['id'] .'">buy</a>';
```

**checkout.php**

```
$dealid = (int)$_GET["id"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $dealid LIMIT 1";
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));

echo $row['name'];
```

What I want to learn is if what I posted is a good way to do this. I guess not. My goal is to pass some data from deal to checkout through a link or a button like image and I don't want to pass for example the title from the url.

What I have in mind is this http://www.groupon.com/st-johns/ where when you click the buy image you proceed to the next step that contains info of the requested to buy deal.

Thank you.

Comment: Either you use query parameters/hidden form fields, or you use sessions. Two choices, either works. It's up to you. Query parameters would be the far better choice for a shopping cart system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the information in a `$_SESSION` variable.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['zipCode'] = "01879";

//zipCode now available on all pages that call session_start()
```

This allows you to store information for the life of the user's session. When the session is destroyed (user navigates away, closes browser, etc.), the information is no longer there. Alternatively, you can use [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) to store this information long-term.

**Addition**

These methods are also more secure than storing the information on the page, as users can modify the DOM elements on the page using a DOM inspector, which most browsers now have. The most secure method is using sessions, as cookie information can also be changed, but is relatively safe if you validate the information there first.

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you agree that my way is not the best right?

Comment: Well, using DOM elements (form inputs, links) allows users to modify the data with a DOM inspector, which most browsers now have.

Comment: So for security reasons, SESSIONS is not the best way to go right ?

Comment: Quite the opposite. Using sessions is, by far, the most secure method.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 ways through which you can pass data into pages through simple php (I am assuming you are not using any PHP Frameworks):

- POST
- GET
- SESSION
- COOKIES

For your answers try to do this with Sessions its the best way I think of.

Comment: Are SESSIONS a better approach to my solution ?

Comment: I always use sessions as they are more secure and they are available throughout the scope of the Application. About your Solution, Yes I think its preferable to use Sessions.